# ConTeXt: Format blockquotes according to punctuation rules

Tags: context, paragraphs, xml, quotation

## Background

Format multi-paragraph quotation with typical English punctuation: quotation marks at the beginning of each paragraph and a single closing quotation mark at the end of the last paragraph.

## Problem

Consider the following XML elements:

```xml
<blockquote>
 <p>Single line quote.</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <p>Double line quote, line 1 of 2.</p>
 <p>Double line quote, line 2 of 2.</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>Dear letter opener,</p>
  <p>Your envelope shredding expediency amazes.</p>
  <p>Signed, CIA</p>
</blockquote>
```

These should produce, respectively:

> "Single line quote."

> "Double line quote, line 1 of 1.
>
> "Double line quote, line 1 of 2."

> "Dear letter opener,
>
> "Your envelope shredding expediency amazes.
>
> "Signed, CIA"

The problem is figuring out what function (`count()`, `position()`, `index()`, `first()`, `last()`, etc.) will allow differentiating the following possibilities:

- Blockquote with 1 paragraph
- Blockquote with 2 paragraphs
- Blockquote with 3 paragraphs or more

## Code

Here's setting the setups:

```
% Block elements
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote|div|p}{xml:*}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote/p[position()==first() and position()!=last()]}{xml:q:began}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote/p[position()!=first() and position()==last()]}{xml:q:ended}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote/p[position()>first() and position()<last()]}{xml:q:middle}
```

Here are the XML setups:

```
% Indented quotations.
\startxmlsetups xml:blockquote
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups
 
\startxmlsetups xml:q:began
  \startquotation
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:q:middle
  \symbol[leftquotation]\xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:q:ended
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopquotation
\stopxmlsetups
```

## Question

How would you distinguish between the three possibilities to produce the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the sets:

```tex
% Block elements
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote|div|p}{xml:*}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote/p}{xml:blockquote:p}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote[count(p)=1]}{xml:blockquote:single}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote[count(p)=2]/p[position()=first()]}{xml:blockquote:began}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote[count(p)=2]/p[position()=last()]}{xml:blockquote:ended}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote[count(p)>2]/p[position()=first()]}{xml:blockquote:began}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote[count(p)>2]/p[position()>first() and position()<last()]}{xml:blockquote:multiple:middle}
\xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{blockquote[count(p)>2]/p[position()=last()]}{xml:blockquote:ended}
```

Then define the different scenarios:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:p
  \startparagraph
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopparagraph
\stopxmlsetups

% Indented quotations.
\startxmlsetups xml:blockquote
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:blockquote:p
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:blockquote:single
  \startquotation
    \ignorespaces\xmlflush{#1}\removeunwantedspaces
  \stopquotation
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:blockquote:began
  \startquotation
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:blockquote:multiple:middle
    \par\xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:blockquote:ended
    \par\xmlflush{#1}
  \stopquotation
\stopxmlsetups
```

Lastly, set up the quotations themselves to auto-quote each line:

```tex
\setupquotation[
  before={\blank},
  after={\blank},
  repeat=yes,
  middle={\symbol[leftquotation]},
]
```

There's repetition that can be addressed and there doesn't seem to be a way to control the protrusion for the first quotation mark.